# jquery- Error swipe page features questions

Tags: jquery, swipeview

I am currently using laravel 4.2 and jquery, swipeview.js
swipe a page script source. 
But it will result in 'Can not read property' style 'of undefined' TypeError.
Unable to find cause

```
var carousel,el,i,page;
    carousel = new SwipeView('#wrapper2', {
        numberOfPages: '{{$users->getLastPage()}}',
        hastyPageFlip: true
    });
    // Load initial data
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        if('{{$users->getLastPage()}}'==1) page = 0;
        else
        page = i==0 ? '{{$users->getLastPage()}}'-1 : i-1;
        divide_user_set(1+page,i,true);
    }
    function divide_user_set(page,i,init) {
        alert(page);
            $.get("/sale/divide_user_set?shop_id={{Auth::user()->shop_id}}&page="+page, function(data){
                    $('#feed'+i).html(data);
            if(init) {
                el = document.createElement('span');
                el.innerHTML = $('#feed'+i).html();
                carousel.masterPages[i].appendChild(el)
            } else {
                el = carousel.masterPages[i].querySelector('span');
                el.innerHTML = $('#feed'+i).html();
            }
            }, "html");
    }

    carousel.onFlip(function () {
        var el,
            upcoming,
            i;

        for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
            upcoming = carousel.masterPages[i].dataset.upcomingPageIndex;
            if (upcoming != carousel.masterPages[i].dataset.pageIndex) {
                divide_user_set(1*upcoming+1,i,false);
            }
        }
    });
```